# Changing background-image after onClick event in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a component, let's say it looks like this:

```
return(
    <div id="container"></div>
)
```

From the beginning it's background image is already set, let's say

```
#container{
background-image: url('./assets/container.jpg');}
```

Now I want to add another element inside the container div that will have onClick event firing function, that will do other things + changing the parent's background-image. Dummy code would be:

```
  handleOnClick(){
     doOtherStuff();
     document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundImage  = "url('./assets/container2.jpg')"}

    return(
    <div id="container">
        <div onClick={()=> handleOnClick()}
    </div>
)
```

Problems are:

It doesn't work, it changes background to blank screen,

After I leave the component and go back to it, it reverts to the old background. Is there any way to avoid that without having the background linked with state? I already have a lot of things in store and it will start to get messy real soon if I start adding more styles to it.

Comment: What does console say? Maybe you got 404 on image?

Comment: Console says nothing, there is no errors. Just changing screen to white. Still doesnt change the fact that its not a proper solution because it gets reset everytime you leave the component sadly

Comment: Provide full code, this way it is unclear... And explain what do you mean by _leave the component_

Comment: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KzQr0aVXqGsQyIG-cgy

I've hacked this quickly and It actually works (besides the first click ;) )

could you provide full code?

Comment: As for the 'persistency' - React recreates the DOM tree when leaving and entering again the component, so without state (or some heavy hacking ;)), I think there is no way to achieve what you desire

Answer (score -1):

This is doable by giving your child the ability to change the state in your parent and holding that logic there. Also, it's much better to control your background shift by using `this.setState`. Just make it a boolean that controls which CSS id to use.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      defaultBackground: true
    }
  }

  toggleChildBackground() {
    const newBackground = !this.state.defaultBackground
    this.setState({defaultBackground: newBackground})
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child
          defaultBackground={this.state.defaultBackground}
          toggleChildBackground={this.toggleChildBackground.bind(this)}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    this.props.toggleChildBackground()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id={this.props.defaultBackground ? 'id1' : 'id2'}>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
          change background
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: So using state is unavoidable, wanted to avoid producing this much code for simple change but I guess it's not how it works in react. Thanks.

Comment: @PalviaOktopus `this.setState` is one of the most powerful features of React. You should be utilizing it.

Comment: I know that, although my store is already huge and wanted to avoid adding yet another thing to it, because it starts to get confusing for me as a beginner, used to do stuff like that in 1 line and now it takes several files.

Comment: The unfortunate truth is that I find myself using this design pattern all the time. It's a necessity if you want to break up your components into manageable pieces.